# Syslog-ng TLS error

Tags: centos, ssl, syslog-ng

I have an issue when trying to forward logs from a CentOS 7

```
[root@localhost ~]# hostnamectl
   Static hostname: localhost.localdomain
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: bcaced37a2944a59bbf6f5b2a2dce3cb
           Boot ID: 99c5a21fccdc41a4acf7bbc67d2ecac2
    Virtualization: kvm
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

I have followed the [Syslog-NG over TLS Setup Guide](https://www.nineproductions.com/syslog-ng-with-tls-setup-for-centralized-logging/).

After I modify the `syslog-ng.conf` file, on the client, to suit my needs with the IP address & port, syslog-ng fails to start/restart

```
@version:3.14
@include "scl.conf"

# syslog-ng configuration file.

[root@localhost ~]# systemctl restart syslog-ng.service
Job for syslog-ng.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status syslog-ng.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status syslog-ng.service -l
● syslog-ng.service - System Logger Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/syslog-ng.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2018-06-11 11:19:59 EEST; 12min ago
     Docs: man:syslog-ng(8)
  Process: 2663 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F $SYSLOGNG_OPTS -p /var/run/syslogd.pid (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 2663 (code=exited, status=2)
   Status: "Starting up... (Mon Jun 11 11:19:59 2018"

Jun 11 11:19:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jun 11 11:19:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logger Daemon.
Jun 11 11:19:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit syslog-ng.service entered failed state.
Jun 11 11:19:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service failed.
Jun 11 11:19:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 11 11:19:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for syslog-ng.service
Jun 11 11:19:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logger Daemon.
Jun 11 11:19:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit syslog-ng.service entered failed state.
Jun 11 11:19:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service failed.
```

The error I seem to get every time, no matter what, is:

```
Error setting up TLS session context; tls_error='(null):(null):(null)'
6-11T11:34:35.204290] Error initializing message pipeline; plugin name='tcp', location='/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf:41:1'
```

It doesn't seem that I have any errors in that file though

```
[root@localhost ~]# syslog-ng -s -f /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
```

Could you please point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to finally figure out what was causing

```
Error setting up TLS session context; tls_error='(null):(null):(null)'
```

In version 3.14 there is a bug. Please use 3.15 or higher:

```
wget https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/czanik/syslog-ng315/repo/epel-7/czanik-syslog-ng315-epel-7.repo
```